# How to install python packages to a running snap package?

Tags: python, snap, pip

As I understand it, Ubuntu Snap encapsulates and manages versions and dependencies.  So if I'm using a python application which is installed as a classic snap, how do I pip install additional packages for the application to use inside the snap, without polluting my non-snap environment?

In this instance I want to add some packages to the 'atom' editor which have a bunch of python package dependencies.

Comment: Does the snap include it's own version of Python? Or does the snap use the system's Python?

Comment: I don't know.  Is there some way to test it?  If I do `snap run --shell atom` and then play with python it presents like the system python. Looking at `/snap/atom/current/snap/manifest.yaml` there are many references to python, but in the `snapcraft.yaml` there are none.  If it had python packaged into it, where would we expect to find it?

Comment: I'm thinking python is not included in the snap.  Which would leave me kinda screwed: wrap the snap in a virtualenv, or modify the snap to include python and site-packages, or suck it up and install to system. :-/

Comment: Related and insightful... https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1670749